# Recommendations for Android TV in Android < 8

Tags: android, android-service, android-tv

I am in stuck with implementation of recommendations (for Android < 8):
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-row

Seems like everything was done, but service even not starting.

I have done the next in **Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />    
<service
        android:name=".additional.androidTV.UpdateRecommendationsService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".additional.androidTV.BootupReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**My UpdateRecommendationsService class:**

```
public class UpdateRecommendationsService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateRecommendationsSe";
    private static final int MAX_RECOMMENDATIONS = 3;

    public UpdateRecommendationsService() {
        super("RecommendationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Updating recommendation cards");
        HashMap<String, List<POJOMovie>> recommendations = new HashMap<>();
        if (recommendations == null) return;

        int count = 0;

        try {
            RecommendationBuilder builder = new RecommendationBuilder()
                    .setContext(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gotposter);

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<POJOMovie>> entry : recommendations.entrySet()) {
                for (POJOMovie movie : entry.getValue()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Recommendation - " + movie.getTitle());

                    builder.setBackground("")
                            .setId(count + 1)
                            .setPriority(MAX_RECOMMENDATIONS - count)
                            .setTitle("test Title")
                            .setDescription("test Description")
//                            .setImage(movie.getPoster())
                            .setIntent(buildPendingIntent(movie))
                            .build();

                    if (++count >= MAX_RECOMMENDATIONS) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (++count >= MAX_RECOMMENDATIONS) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to update recommendation", e);
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent buildPendingIntent(POJOMovie movie) {
        Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//        detailsIntent.putExtra("POJOMovie", movie);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(detailsIntent);
        // Ensure a unique PendingIntents, otherwise all
        // recommendations end up with the same PendingIntent
        detailsIntent.setAction(movie.getId());


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return pendingIntent;
    }
}
```

**RecommendationBuilder class:**

```
public class RecommendationBuilder {
    private static final String TAG = "RecommendationBuilder";
    private static final String BACKGROUND_URI_PREFIX = "content://com.example.android.tvleanback.recommendation/";
    private Context mContext;

    private int mId;
    private int mPriority;
    private int mSmallIcon;
    String mTitle;
    String mDescription;
    String mImageUri;
    String mBackgroundUri;
    private PendingIntent mIntent;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    private int mProgress = -1;

    public RecommendationBuilder() {
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setId(int id) {
        mId = id;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setSmallIcon(int resourceId) {
        mSmallIcon = resourceId;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setPriority(int priority) {
        mPriority = priority;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setIntent(PendingIntent intent) {
        mIntent = intent;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setDescription(String description) {
        mDescription = description;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setImage(String uri) {
        mImageUri = uri;
        return this;
    }

    public RecommendationBuilder setBackground(String uri) {
        mBackgroundUri = uri;
        return this;
    }

    public Notification build() throws IOException {

        if (mNotificationManager == null) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                        .setContentTitle("test Title2")
                        .setContentText("test Description2")
                        .setPriority(mPriority)
                        .setLocalOnly(true)
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red))
                        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_RECOMMENDATION)
//                        .setLargeIcon(R.drawable.gotposter)
                        .setSmallIcon(mSmallIcon)
                        .setContentIntent(mIntent)
                        .setExtras(extras))
                .build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, notification);
        mNotificationManager = null;

        return notification;
    }

}
```

**And BootupReceiver:**

```
public class BootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "BootupActivity";

    private static final long INITIAL_DELAY = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BootupActivity initiated");
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction()).endsWith(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
                scheduleRecommendationUpdate(context);
            }
        } else{
            Log.d(TAG, "other service for higher API started");
        }
    }

    private void scheduleRecommendationUpdate(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling recommendations update");

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent recommendationIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateRecommendationsService.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, recommendationIntent, 0);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                INITIAL_DELAY,
//                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                alarmIntent);
    }.
}
```

As I've understood when app starts service should be started automatically too.

I've set debug point for every row in this classes but nothing happening. What is wrong with my code? Have I forgotten something in manifest?

**UPD 21.09.2020:** unfortunately, still looking for the answer.

**UPD 02.02.2021:** unfortunately, still looking for the answer.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? Now I also met problem same as you. If you can, please share to me your solution? thank you

Comment: @Duong.Nguyen, nah, I haven't. That project was frozen by my company and I've postponed this issue... Maybe will try something tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your BroadcastReceiver is set to not be exported, which means it cannot receive messages from anything with a different user ID (meaning only itself if you haven't explicitly set that in the manifest). If you set exported=true, then that should enable your receiver to get the boot completed message. Note that you must run the app at least once after installing it before it can receive broadcasts.

As a side note, I'd recommend not calling your BroadcastReceiver "BootupActivity" since "Activity" is a very specific thing in Android. Something like BootupReceiver is more clear.

Comment: forgot to answer - I have tried your advice several month ago and set `exported=true` but nothing changed. Tried this now one more time - same. All code still the same except I renamed `BootupActivity` on `BootupReceiver`)